# How to use both setValidator() and setInputMask() for QLineEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qregexp, input-mask

I have a line edit where the user has to enter in the 12-hour time format. This is a touch based application and I have my own keyboard and this keyboard does not have the ***":"*** (colon) character. So, I am using an Input Mask for that purpose.  But I have only `setInputMask( 99:99 )` option which allows the user to enter any number whereas I have to restrict the user to the 12-hour format.

I went through some examples with QRegexp but I couldn't have the ":" like in the Input Mask. Can anyone point me on how to implement?

Comment: What about using `QTimeEdit`?

Comment: @hank No I can't use it here. Requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the Qt Docs explicitly say that we shall "use masks together with validators" if we want range control in out `QLineEdits`, this seems to be not that trivial. At least other people has similar problems. But mybe this helps:

Subclass the `QLineEdit` and override `focusInEvent()` and `setValidator()` as follows:

----------------- mylineedit.h ----------------------

```
#ifndef MYLINEEDIT_H
#define MYLINEEDIT_H

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QFocusEvent>
#include <QRegExpValidator>

class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    const QValidator *validator;

public:

    MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void setValidator(const QValidator *v);

protected:

    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e);
};

#endif // MYLINEEDIT_H
```

------------------- mylineedit.cpp -------------------

```
#include "mylineedit.h"

MyLineEdit::MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent): QLineEdit(parent)
{

}

void MyLineEdit::setValidator(const QValidator *v)
{
    validator = v;
    QLineEdit::setValidator(v);
}

void MyLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);
    clear();
    setInputMask("");
    setValidator(validator);
}
```

For the `MyLineEdit` object itself we use a `QRegExp` to allow only to enter time in 12 hour format without a colon at this point: 1152 e.g. When the user ends editing the lineedit gets an InpuMask of the form `"HH:HH"` which makes 1152 to 11:52. The focus is cleared. If the user focuses again to the lineedit, it is cleared and the `QRegExp` is set again and the user enteres the new time 1245 e.g. and so on...

--------------------- rootwindow.h --------------------

```
#ifndef ROOTWINDOW_H
#define ROOTWINDOW_H

#include "mylineedit.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtDebug>

class RootWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    QWidget *widgetCentral;
    MyLineEdit *line;

public:

    RootWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~RootWindow();

private slots:

    void slotLineEdited();
};

#endif // ROOTWINDOW_H
```

-------------- rootwindow.cpp ----------------------

```
#include "rootwindow.h"

RootWindow::RootWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setCentralWidget(widgetCentral = new QWidget);

    line = new MyLineEdit(widgetCentral);
    line->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(  QRegExp("[0][0-9][0-5][0-9]|[1][0-2][0-5][0-9]")  ));

    connect(line, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(slotLineEdited()));
}

RootWindow::~RootWindow()
{

}

void RootWindow::slotLineEdited()
{
    line->setInputMask("HH:HH");
    line->clearFocus();
}
```

---------------------- main.cpp --------------------------

```
#include "rootwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    RootWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It seems a little over the top but actually it is not that much new code and you do not need a colon key on your keyboard.